# What is the meaning of 'i' in function(d,i){return i})?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the meaning of 'i'?
I read:

'i gives you the index of the current item'..but i can't understand ' index of the current item....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dataArray = [20, 40, 50];

      var canvas =  d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width",500)
                  .attr("height",500);

      var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect") 
                  .data(dataArray)
                  .enter() 
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr("width",function(d){return d*10;})
                  .attr("height",50)
                  .attr("y", function(d,i){return i*100}); 
    </script>
```

If i don't give *100 in that coding
Rectangles overlap each other...

Answer (score 0):

From your given example data

```
var dataArray = [20, 40, 50];
```

As rectangles are appended to the canvas, each one is passed to the function that sets the Y value as follows -

d - The actual data. In this case that will be either 20, 40, or 50. But it can be more complex, such as an object, depending on the data you are appending.

i - The index of said data within the data array. As there are 3 items within your data array, these would be 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

While appending, the Y function uses the index of the data within the array to appropriately space out the rectangles such that they do not overlap. Similarly, d is used to create rectangles with different widths by referencing the data.